# Mask a number column with text

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a SharePoint list, with custom columns.  I need to use a NUMBER column, but mask each number as text like the below:

Very Satisfied

Satisfied

Dissatisfied

I need each item above to equal a score.

So basically, my user selects Very Satisfied and it shows as Very Satisfied, but in the background, sharepoint knows its value as equaling 3, which i will use to calculate an overall score.

How do i mask the number as being 3 but it shows Very Satisfied instead of the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a list "Satisfaction" with two columns: index, title
- Add 3 items (1, "Very satisified", 2, ....)
- From your current list add lookup list to "Satisfaction", to the Title column. Also select "index" to be included.
- When a user selects "Very satisfied", in the extra "index" column you can find the numeric value.

Comment: Where am i adding the 3 items to?  Should the index column be a number and obviously the title should be text?

Comment: Three items are added to Satisfaction list. Index is indeed number. Title is by default text.

Comment: can the 3 items be a combined answer?  Like theres a questions with 3 options. each one of those items has a different index?

Comment: I don't understand you. There is only one list with those 3 items. Another list, e.g. the list with questions, references that list and the user picks on of the 3 items for the value of satisfaction. Both the value (e.g. "Very satisfied") as the index (e.g. "1") is then stored in the questions list.